# step function working only for non negative numbers

Tags: functions, step-function

I want to create a step function $f(x,n)$ that works like this:

[image]

$n$ indicates the size of the interval and $x$ is the position in the $x$-axis.

I thought the following way:

1. Let $k = x\div n$ (this maps the intervals to $[\dots,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,\dots]$).
2. if $k \; mod \; 2 < 1$, return $1$, otherwise return $0$.

This works fine for non-negative numbers, but fails at negatives. How can I fix this function? Is there any better approach?

Comment: Are you implementing this in a programming language? The usual mathematical definition of the "mod" function lets this definition work fine. Programming languages, however, differ on what "mod" does to negative numbers (e.g. C and C++ have integer division round towards zero, so the mod operator ends up being a signed remainder - breaking your definition!)

Comment: Yes, I'm programming but I'm asking to see if there is another possibility of function that I'm missing.

Answer (score 1):

What you want in precise terms is $k=\lfloor x/n\rfloor$. Python's `//` operator computes exactly that; in C and C++ you will need to import `floor()`.

Comment: Do you mean my function should be `if ( floor(x/n) % 2 < 1 ) return 1; otherwise return 0`? I tried that and didn't work with negatives.

Comment: @Daniel You need floating-point division.